# Combobox population problem

Tags: c#

So I have a combobox -  the designer code:

```
this.cmbStatusBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    "Ordered",
    "Cooking",
    "In-transit",
    "Delivered"});
```

The formload code:

```
if (mainForm.boolEdit == true)
    {
        this.cmbStatusBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Cooking",
        "In-transit",
        "Delivered"});
    }
    else
    {
        this.cmbStatusBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Ordered"});
    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to make the combobox have different values.
As things stand, i get both whats in the designer and in formload in the comboboxes.

How can i stop this?

I also have an edit function, so when i edit a record, i want the combo box to be populated by what is already saved.

Just a random question, can you stop the user entering a value that isn't in the combo box?

Thankyou

Comment: Set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList to prevent user entering a value which is not in the list

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the current contents then you'll need to call

```
this.cmbStatusBox.Items.Clear();
```

before adding your new values.

[`ComboBox` MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)
[`ComboBox.Items` MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx)

> The DropDownStyle property also specifies whether the text portion can be edited.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=VS.100).aspx)

The values are:

> **Simple** Specifies that the list is always visible and that the text portion is editable. This means that the user can enter a new value and is not limited to selecting an existing value in the list.
>
> **DropDown** Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and that the text portion is editable. This means that the user can enter a new value and is not limited to selecting an existing value in the list. When using this setting, the [Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.append(v=VS.100).aspx) value of [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=VS.100).aspx) works the same as the [SuggestAppend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.suggestappend(v=VS.100).aspx) value. This is the default style.
>
> **DropDownList** Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and that the text portion is not editable. This means that the user cannot enter a new value. Only values already in the list can be selected. The list displays only if [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=VS.100).aspx) is [Suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.suggest(v=VS.100).aspx) or [SuggestAppend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.suggestappend(v=VS.100).aspx).

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the items from the designer code.

Comment: This worked, with a drawback!
Before, when i edited a record, it would populate the dropdown in my edit form with what was saved.
Now it doesnt, so everything else comes back up for editing, but this combobox is blank until something is selected.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Luke: I defer to ChrisF's answer